# Transformation rule in differential geometry

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, general-relativity, jacobian, index-notation

I am reading Walds General Relativity and am looking at Question 8, Chapter 2. In the solutions to this question it states that the metric is determined by the transformation rule

$$g_{\alpha\beta}^{'} = \frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{'\alpha}}\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{'\beta}}g_{\mu\nu}$$

I really cannot see how this identity works. I cannot see how the partial derivatives act on the tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$. Nor can I see why the 's are on the bottom of the partial derivatives.

Next is says that $\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{'\alpha}}=({J^{-1}})^{\mu}_{\alpha}$. I cannot see why this should be $J^{-1}$ and not $J$?

Then it says that

$$g_{\alpha\beta}^{'} = ({J^{-1}})^{\mu}_{\alpha}g_{\mu\nu}({J^{-1}})^{\nu}_{\beta}$$
I cannot see here why you are allowed to swap round the partial derivatives and the tensor.

Comment: I would appreciate if someone could think of a better title for this question as well

Comment: The derivatives **don't** "act on" the tensor.  The numbers given by those derivatives are **multiplied** by the tensor.

Comment: @user247327 I thought the the $g_{\mu\nu}$ would lower the indices but again not sure what this would mean. Also the tensor is on the far right so it is not clear whether it could act on the partial derivatives or not

Comment: What is your background in differential geometry?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval walds book and a course on differentiable manifolds at university (which was more like calculus)

Comment: As per asked in comments to solutions below I have edited the Jacobian part of the question

Comment: Well, it's a $pointwise$ equation, i.e it is to read as $$g'_{\alpha \beta}(p) = \frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x'^{\alpha}}(p) \frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x'^{\beta}}(p) g_{\mu \nu}(p)$$ and the $\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x'^{\alpha}}(p)$, say, are just real numbers. As are the entries of the Jacobian at any given Point, so swapping some real numbers shouldn't be a deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be read as an addition to the post of Upax.

**Some setup**

Let $M$ be the spacetime at hand (whose dimension is $n$). It is to be emphasized, that your equation only holds in 
local coordinates, i.e in a [chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(topology)#Charts). Let $U,U' \subset M$ with $U \cap U' \neq \emptyset$, and let $$x:U \to \mathbb{R}^n, p \mapsto (x^1(p),...,x^n(p))$$
$$x': U' \to \mathbb{R}^n, p \mapsto (x'^1(p),...,x'^n(p))$$
be the chosen charts, i.e, the coordinates at hand. We denote by $x^{\mu}, x'^{\alpha}$ 
(where $\mu, \alpha \in \{1,...,n\}$)the mappings $$ x^{\mu}:U \to \mathbb{R}, p \mapsto x^{\mu}(p)$$
$$x'^{\alpha}:U' \to \mathbb{R}, p \mapsto x'^{\alpha}(p).$$
In the same manner, $x^{\nu}$ and $x'^{\beta}$ are defined.
Observe that the different choice of indices is merely a matter of convention!
Locally, these charts determine [frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_(linear_algebra)) fields, i.e, they determine a basis for each $p \in U \cap U'$ (we restrict ourself to the intersection since your equation is meaningless elsewhere), which are frequently denoted by $$\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}, ..., \frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}\} = \{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu }}\}_{\mu=1,...,n}$$
$$\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x'^1}, ..., \frac{\partial}{\partial x'^n}\}= \{\frac{\partial}{\partial x'^{\alpha}}\}_{\alpha=1,..,n},$$
(again, the indices are equivalently denoted by $\nu$ and $\beta$ respectively). See also
[this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Basis_of_the_tangent_space_at_a_point) for more information on how exactly this basis is defined.
As you (hopefully) know, the metric is given by a (family of) mapping(s) 
$$g_p: T_pM \times T_pM \to \mathbb{R}, (X_p,Y_p) \mapsto g_p(X_p,Y_p)$$ 
which varies smoothly with $p$, i.e, the mapping $p \mapsto g_p(X_p,Y_p)$ is smooth for any choice of [vector fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field#Vector_fields_on_manifolds) $X$ and $Y$. See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#Riemannian_metrics) for the case of definite signature (which carries over to the indefinite case).

**How this (hopefully) helps**

Using the preceeding, your equation $$g'_{\alpha \beta} = \frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x'^{\alpha}} \frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x'^{\beta}} g_{\mu \nu}$$
reads as
 $$g\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x'^{\alpha}}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x'^{\beta}}\right)=  \frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x'^{\alpha}} \frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x'^{\beta}}g\left({\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}}\right).$$
Now, since $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}\}_{\mu=1,...,n}$ and $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x'^{\alpha}}\}_{\alpha=1,...,n}$ are frame fields on $U \cap U'$, there does exist a (smooth) family $A=(A_{\mu \alpha})_{\mu \alpha =1,...,n}$ of matrices (i.e for $p \in U \cap U'$ we have $A(p): T_pM \to T_pM$) satisfying $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} = A_{\mu \alpha} \frac{\partial}{\partial x'^{\alpha}}$.
At this point, it's linear algebra (you only have to verify your equation pointwise).
To do this, I suggest you recall the definition of the [Gramian Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) and use it's transformation properties (you should try to understand how the Gramian Matrix is related to the ''metric tensor''-observe that you deal with indefinite signature, so not all properties do hold). Finally, using this and the definition of our frame fields, you should be able to verify that the sought matrix $A$ is indeed the (inverse) of the jacobian corresponding to the coordinates. How the change of coordinates affects the frame fields can be found (or, at least, deduced from) in any book on differential geometry (you don't need the definite signature for that), as in [do Carmo - Riemannian Geometry](https://smile.amazon.de/Riemannian-Geometry-Mathematics-Theory-Applications/dp/0817634908/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1541345706&sr=8-1&keywords=do%20carmo%20riemannian%20geometry). I do, however, encourage you to take some book on pseudo riemannian geometry and read that too.

**A Remark**

It did not execute the caluclations myself thus I might have confused the indices: It might very well be that at some point the indices should be written as (e.g) ''$x_{\mu}$'' instead of ''$x^{\mu}$''. Thus, if you find that it does not make sense the way I wrote it, don't worry too much.

Comment: Do you think you need a course of differential geometry before reading Wald's General Relativity?

Comment: Also I still dont see the Jacobian bit

Comment: That depends on how precisely you want to understand the book, I'd say. It definetly wouldn't hurt to use one as addition (but I don't think you need stuff like the sphere theorem -get comfortable with the use of charts and viewing everything locally). Keep in mind that (most) books on general relativity are designed for physicists and thus do not care (as much) about mathematical precision, the focus is on the physical implications.

Comment: For the Jacobian part: Where are you stuck? If you performed some calculation, it'd help if you could edit that into your question so we can try to tackle it!

As for my previous comment: I didn't read Wald's book, so I don't know his level of rigor.

Comment: Edited the jacobian part of my question

Comment: Just stumbled upon this, I think it might help you (if you didn't happen to stumble upon it yourself):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor#Components_of_the_metric
its pretty much the calculation you need.

Comment: Good efforts Creo, some tricky stuff here

Answer (score 1):

Let consider the position vector $r$ of a point P relative to the common origin of two orthonormal bases with basis vectors $e_j$ and $f_j$. The coordinates of P in the rectangular systems defined by these bases are denoted by $x_j$ and $\overline{x}_i$. So we can write:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{r}=x^i \mathbb{e_i}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{r} = \overline{x}^j \mathbb{\overline{e}_j}
\end{equation}
the relationship between the two sets $x_j$ and $\overline{x}_i$ is given by:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{r} =x^i \overline{a}_{ij} \mathbb{\overline{e}_j} = {a}_{ji} x^i \mathbb{\overline{e}_j}  
\end{equation}
This is because the basis $\mathbb{e_i}$ can be written as the product $\overline{a}_{ij} \mathbb{\overline{e}_j}$ where $\overline{a}_{ih} {a}_{hj}= \delta_{ij}$.  By comparing the above relation with the right hand side of the $\mathbb{r} = \overline{x}^j \mathbb{\overline{e}_j}$ we have that $\overline{x}^j=a_{ji} x^i$. The importance of the above relationships is due to the fact that they allow us to specify the transformation of any given function of the
coordinates under a change of orthonormal bases.
The metric tensor $g_{\mu \nu}$ establishes a natural direct product
on the tangent plane $T_p S$ that ultimately leads to formulas for length of vectors in $T_p S$, arc length, angle between vectors in $T_p S$ and area formulas
on S. It is the restriction of the usual dot product in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to the tangent plane $T_p S$. Based on what I wrote, you can consider the product of  2 vectors $A$ and $B$. Their components transform under a change of basis as
\begin{equation}
\overline{A_j} = a_{jh} A_h 
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\overline{B_k} = a_{kl} B_l 
\end{equation}
So that
\begin{equation}
\overline{A_k} \overline{B_k} = a_{jh} a_{kl} A_h B_l 
\end{equation} 
A set og quantities $T_{jk}$ is said to constitute the components of an affine tensor of rank 2, if under the orthogonal coordinate
transformation  $\overline{x}^j=a_{ji} x^i$, these quantities transform according to the transformation law
\begin{equation}
\overline{T_{jk}}  = a_{jh} a_{kl} T_{hl} 
\end{equation}
Since
\begin{equation}
a_{jh} =\frac{\partial \overline{x}^j}{\partial x^h}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
a_{kl} =\frac{\partial \overline{x}^k}{\partial x^l}
\end{equation}
you can conclude that the first fundamental form $g$ is a tensor of rank (0,2).